# Why is it that my code is only showing the last element in the array even though It should be showing the element with the most amount of characters

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector, max

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

vector<string> createvector() {
    vector<string> words;
    string names;
    cout << "Please enter 5 different words: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> names;
        words.push_back(names);
    }
    return (words);
}
void mostchar(vector<string> words) {
    string w1 = words[0];
    string largestword;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        if (words[i] > w1) {
            largestword = words[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The largest word is: " << largestword;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    string names;
    words = createvector();
    mostchar(words);
}
```

I do not understand why it's picking the last element or the second to last element every time. Right I've tried to change for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) but it makes no difference to what I do.

Comment: The `>` operator does not compare string length.  It is comparing value (for ordering).  To compare length use `.size()` or `.length()`.

Comment: `words[i] > w1` compares always with `words[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you are comparing strings in the lexicographical order.

```
if (words[i] > w1) {
```

Secondly you always comparing with the word in the first element of the array

```
if (words[i] > w1) {
```

and the variable `w1` is not being changed within the loop. So any last element in the vector that is greater than `w1` will be assigned to the variable `largestword`.

Using the for loop the function can look the following way

```
void mostchar( const std::vector<std::string> &words ) 
{
    size_t largestword = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < words.size(); i++ ) 
    {
        if ( words[largestword].size() < words[i].size() ) 
        {
            largestword = i;
        }
    }

    if ( largestword != words.size() )
    {
        std::cout << "The largest word is: " << words[largestword] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that in general case the user can pass to the function an empty vector. You must check such a possibility within the function.

Bear in mind that there is standard algorithm `std::max_element` that can be used instead of manually written for loop.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

void mostchar( const std::vector<std::string> &words ) 
{
    auto largestword = std::max_element( std::begin( words ), std::end( words ),
                                         []( const auto &a, const auto &b )
                                         {
                                             return a.size() < b.size();
                                         } );

    if ( largestword != std::end( words ) )
    {
        std::cout << "The largest word is: " << *largestword << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here:

1: You should use something like `.length()` to compare "length"

2: You are comparing the next word in the array to `words[0]` every time.

**EDIT: To further explain this, there is an assignment of `string w1 = words[0];`. `w1` is then used in the `if` in the `for` loop here:**

```
string w1 = words[0];
string largestword;
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    if (words[i] > w1) {
        largestword = words[i];
    }
}
```

**resulting in the value of `words[0]` being the value repeatedly compared in the loop.**

Adjust the comparison line to `if (words[i].length() > largestword.length())` and that solves both problems. You can elminate `w1` entirely this way as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

vector<string> createvector() {
    vector<string> words;
    string names;
    cout << "Please enter 5 different words: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> names;
        words.push_back(names);
    }
    return (words);
}
void mostchar(vector<string> words) {
    string largestword;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (words[i].length() > largestword.length()) {
            largestword = words[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The largest word is: " << largestword;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    string names;
    words = createvector();
    mostchar(words);
}
```